# Efficient updating in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a Dataframe with several thousand rows. Each row represent the properties of an asset.

e.g.

```
......... prop1, prop2

Asset A   value1A, value2A
Asset B   value1B, value2B
```

I am going to write this into rows such as...

Asset A, prop1, value

Here's a code snippet:

```
for field in fields:
    frame = reference([field.name], assets)
    for asset in frame.index:
        a = Symbol.objects.get(name=asset)
        value = frame[field.name][asset]
        SymbolProperty.objects.update_or_create(symbol=a, field=field, value=value)
```

Unfortunately this is rather slow and I am sure this could be done a lot faster.

Note that I ask the Symbol table for each value to fetch the Symbol. Also update_or_create is called for each individual entry. Your help is very appreciated

Comment: In my work I faced the same problem. My decision was to use [bulk update] and [bulk create]
To speed up process even more, consider using above functions with [threads]. [Here] I shared a code snippet, guess you can grab some ideas from it, but keep in mind that you can face deadlock problem if your table holds a lot of data( as I faced with MariaDB and InnoDB tables, maybe Postgres handles it better), so you have to implement a way of restart failed transaction. [bulk update]:https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update
[bulk create]:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#